# Stop Screenlets from minimizing

Tags: compiz, minimize, screenlets

I've setup my screenlets exactly the way that I want them, but I don't have a quick access to any of them. The screenlet config offers me the following : keep above,below, sticky, locky, widget.

Out of these only [treat as Widget](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/35447)  seems to be of any use here. I just looked at this in detail and thought it was what I was looking for. It might have been a workaround for the issue (instead of minimizing I would just press <kbd>F9</kbd>. But this means that the widget hides itself from the normal desktop, which is not what I want.

What I want is that on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, I should **see the desktop with my screenlets there**. I don't want them to minimize with the rest of the windows.

As a final struggle, I've thought of a solution using compiz to declare the screenlet windows as non-minimizing, but surely there must be a better way than that. (Instructions for this would be helpful as well - I'm not sure what to enter in the rule matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the package [compizconfig-settings-manager[image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) if you haven't already.
2. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and click *General Options*.
3. Uncheck *Hide Skip Taskbar Windows*.

   [image]
4. Now hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> won't minimize your screenlets:

   [image]

Comment: I would vote over and over again for the animated gifs.