# Stop Screenlets from minimizing (in gnome shell)

Tags: gnome, compiz, minimize, screenlets

I know there is a similar question already ([Stop Screenlets from minimizing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49386/stop-screenlets-from-minimizing)) but the solution for the question uses compizconfig-settings-manager which doesn't work with Gnome Shell. Is there any other workaround so that when I press Win+D, the screenlets along with the desktop is shown? 
A shell extension which allows certain windows to 'skip taskbar' can do the above job, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told that the [Show Desktop Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/) extension that I forked from MGSE's Bottom Panel/Window List extension has the ability to do what you ask, but not in the same manner. But hopefully it is somewhat helpful to you.

This extension creates a button on the panel, as opposed to having a shortcut. I have been working on getting a keybinding set but I still don't have the js knowledge required for that, so any coding help possible is always appreciated and the git link is on the e.g.o link above.

This *should* only minimize windows and not screenlets according to comments I have received. I have not tested this, but I would love feedback on it from someone actually using some kind of widgets, so if you do test it let me know and I'll add a note to the extensions info with some due credit.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does work the way you mentioned. It would have been great if it worked with some keybinding. But for now, this would suffice.

Comment: I am going to try to get a keybinding going. Don't hold me to it, but I will try harder.

Comment: I have used xdotool & xbindkeys to simulate the clicking of your extension's button using a custom keybinding. This is not the best way to go about it, but can work till the extension gets a keybinding option.